# Xcode detect iOS version and show storyboard accordingly

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, ios7

I want to show one storyboard to my iOS6 users and another to iOS7 users. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    //load and show ios6 storyboard
}
else {
    //load and show ios7 storyboard
}
```

Comment: does not work properly on iOS 6.1.3 because for 6.1.3 iOS version it float value is 993.0 and NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 is 992.0 som for 6.1.3 version you will make WRONG assumption that it is iOS 7 or greater

Comment: @NikolayShubenkov - I took this code from the iOS7 Transition Guide.  (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1

Comment: @NikolayShubenkov - interestingly I see ... #define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_0  993.00
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1  993.00 in NSObjCRuntime.h

Comment: Actually I investigated this not intentionally, but when my app crashed on iOS 6.1.3 device. The crash was because after checking iOS version by this method system detects it version to be like iOS 7 or greater. Then I checked this NSFoundationVersionNumber values in runtime

Answer (score 3):

You can get the iOS version using this code:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

For example, to detect iOS 6, you could do something like:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion hasPrefix:@"6"]) {
    // ...
}
```

Then, to load different storyboards for iOS 6 and 7, you would do something like:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion hasPrefix:@"6"]) {
    myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_6" bundle:nil];
} else {
    myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_7" bundle:nil];
}
```

---

**EDIT:** as noted in the other answers, an arguably better way to detect iOS version is to use the NSFoundationVersionNumber, as no string parsing of the systemVersion is needed.

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_6" bundle:nil];
} else {
    myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_7" bundle:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in AppDelegate (very important)

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = nil; 
 if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    storyboard =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iOS7_AND_ABOVE" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 } else {
    storyboard =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iOS_below_7" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 }
```

Comment: Xcode doesn't seem to know what NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 is. It only knows up to 5_1. What's up with that?

Comment: @Chase Robers Use iOS SDK 7 for that. NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 is defined on IOS 7 SDK only

Comment: My mac is too old to let me upgrade the OS to the minimum version required by the xcode update so I am just out of luck...

Comment: will fail to work properly for iOS 6.1.3 as it has larger float foundation value than NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1